# How to tell searchDisplayController that we're done

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Say I have a `searchDisplayController`. When I click on the `searchbar`, 3 things happen

1. `Keyboard` show up
2. Cancel button show up
3. A black transparent layer show up. This will sometimes be replaced by some table.

If I do `[searchBar resignFirstResponder]` the `keyboard` is hidden. Good. However, the black transparent layer and the cancel button is still there.

It's as if the `searchdisplaycontroller` still think that I am still using that `searchbar`. How to tell the  that I am done?

Clicking that black transparent layer will tell `searchDisplayController` we're done. How to achieve that same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling:

```
[searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```